# Text height with multirow in a tabularx table

Tags: tables, tabularx, multirow

I'm facing trouble with `multirow`, when I used `multirow` in the last column of the table, the text becomes very close to the top margin and the text is not justified, while in other columns and rows text height is okay.  I also used `makecell[t]` and `pbox` both of them help to justify text however text height remains an issue also they both worked without `multirow`, so I wanted to use `multirow` and normal text height not close to the top margin, can you please help here.  I'm sharing code and an image.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{IEEEtran}
\begin{table*}[t]
\caption{ }
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4.5pt}
\label{Table:1} %cXXX  {\linewidth} 
\begin{tabularx} {\textwidth} {|c|p{3cm}| p{5cm}|p{7.5cm}|}
\hline
 \multicolumn{1}{|c}{AAAAAA(s)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{AAAAAAA(s)} %& \multicolumn{1}{c}{ Source(s)}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{AAAAAAAA (s)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{AAAAA(s)}
          
\\
\hline
\& &\multirow{4}{7.5cm}{{}} \\ \cline{1-3} %\cline{4-5}



& & &  \\ \cline{1-3}


 & & &    \\\cline{1-3}
\& &  &   \\\cline{1-3}

\textit{Our work}&   & &   \\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a compilable MWE that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. Otherwise we need to guess which packages you use. Also, I think your code has some issues, considering the appearance of `\&` twice.

Comment: Did you try `\multirow[t]{5}{7.5cm}{`<your text here>`}`?

Comment: @JasperHabicht,  I added document class, and yes I tried it, it helps to adjust the height but then text remains unjustified, so meaning if I correct one thing the other creates a problem.

Comment: You shouldn't use a `tabularx` environment if it has no `X` column.

Comment: Please prepare a complete and compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get. If I take your code, add the missing packages, I get the following output which is quite different from what you show in your question. https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPsJY.png

Answer (score 4):

Your MWE is not complete and contain errors, so I can only guess, what you like to have. Anyway, if you use `tabularx` table, at list one column should be of `X` type. For example, the last one:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[t]
\caption{ }
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4.5pt}
\label{Table:1} %cXXX  {\linewidth}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} {|c|p{3cm}| p{5cm}|X|}
    \hline
AAAAAA(s)   & AAAAAAA(s)    & AAAAAAAA (s)  & AAAAA(s)  \\
    \hline
            &               &               & \multirow{4}{=}{\lipsum[66]}                   
                                                        \\ \cline{1-3}
            &               &               &           \\ \cline{1-3}
            &               &               &           \\ \cline{1-3}
            &               &               &           \\ \cline{1-3}
\textit{Our work}
            &               &               &           \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
Using it, your table will not protrude out of text borders, as you can see on mage below. It is also not clear, why you for column headers use `multicolumn` cells. They only overwrite column settings and make a mess with vertical lines.

[image]

**Addendum:**
For exercise and fun you may investigate features of the `tabularray` packages. Using it, the code of above table can be:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabularray}

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}[t]
    \caption{ }
    \label{Table:1}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,            % lines in table
             colspec= {c Q[j,wd=3cm] Q[j,wd=5cm] X[j]},
             rowsep=3pt,                % vertical space between rows borders
                                        % and (heigher) contents in it
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries}, % text in the first row is boldface
             vspan = even               % height of rows spanned by multi row cell
                                        % is evenly distributed
             }  % table preamble, defaine its layout
AAAAAA(s)   & AAAAAAA(s)    & AAAAAAAA (s)  & AAAAA(s)  \\
            &               &               & \SetCell[r=5]{j} \lipsum[1] % define multi row cell
                                                        \\
            &               &               &           \\
            &               &               &           \\
            &               &               &           \\
\textit{Our work}
            & short text    & \lipsum[1][1] &           \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

For more information please read package's dpcumentation.

[image]

Comment: As for why the OP uses `multicolumn` cells in the table header, I think, that they want to omit the vertical lines in the header. But this is only my guess ...

Comment: @JasperHabicht, probably you are right, but to me is nonlogical why they then should be in the table body ...